# Utilizing parallel query execution in Postgresql for SELECT INTO

Tags: sql, postgresql, parallel-processing, query-performance

Is parallel query execution in Postgresql supported for SELECT INTO queries?

Comment: What do you mean by parallel? what's the case? what do you want to achieve? your question is too open, you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Parallel execution is not available for DDL statements - only for read only queries.

The deprecated `SELECT .. INTO ...` creates a new table and thus it qualifies as DDL.

It is also recommended to use `CREATE TABLE .. AS SELECT ...` instead.

Update: Postgres 11 (to be released end of 2018) will support parallel query execution for `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...`