# How to insert a result of a parallelized SELECT query into a table, in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/when-can-parallel-query-be-used.html,

> "Even when it is in general possible for parallel query plans to be
>   generated, the planner will not generate them for a given query if any
>   of the following are true:
>       The query writes any data or locks any database rows. If a query contains a data-modifying operation either at the top level or within
>   a CTE, no parallel plans for that query will be generated. This is a
>   limitation of the current implementation which could be lifted in a
>   future release."

Indeed, when I try to insert result of a parallel **`SELECT`** query into a table ( either by **`SELECT.. INTO`** or by **`WITH..SELECT..INTO`** ), the query is not executed as parallel query.

**My question is:** Is there any way to trick the Postgresql so that a **`SELECT`** query is executed as a parallel query and then its result inserted into a table?

Comment: As [I said before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47057891/330315) the deprecated `SELECT ... INTO ..` is a DDL statement and there is no way to make Postgres use parallel execution for DDL (or DML) statements.

Comment: This is not related to the true-`[PARALLEL]` process scheduling. Even the "just"-`[CONCURRENT]` process execution is restricted from doing "promised" query-plan, because the implementing engine simply rejects any attempt, which would go into resolving the "just"-`[CONCURRENT]`-update-propagations beyond the scope of safe-mods ( and all other non-`[SERIAL]` transactions ( modifications ) were not implemented in the engine to run safely under the "promised" query-plan --- so they rather get refused, or re-arranged into an old-&-safe pure-`[SERIAL]` transaction ordering ). "Tricking" is risky ...

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick with psql -o parameter.

i.e.

**Step1:**

```
call psql -h localhost -d dbname -U username -c "select * from vw_FBigTable_extract" -o FBigTable_extract.csv -A -t -F ","
```

**Step2:**

```
call psql -h localhost -d dbname -U username -c "COPY t_FBigTable_extract FROM 'FBigTable_extract.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER ',', HEADER FALSE, ENCODING 'windows-1252')"
```

Sometimes works faster then non-parallel approach.